# Why is amazon S3 clients location dependents?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am playing with `amazon-s3`. My use case is to just list keys starting with a prefix.

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3', "eu-west-1")
response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket="my-bucket", MaxKeys=1, Prefix="my/prefix/")
for content in response['Contents']:
    print(content['Key'])
```

`my-bucket` is located in `use1`. I am surprised that my python client from `euw1` is able to do such requests. For reference, my scala client:

```scala
val client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build()

client.listObjectsV2("my-bucket", "my-prefix")
```

which gives an error

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket is in this region: us-east-1. Please use this region to retry the request

which is expected.

My question is, why the s3Client is location dependant ? Is there any advantage to choose the right location ? Is there any hidden cost to not match the location ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, why the s3Client is location dependant

Because buckets are regional resources even if they pretend not to be.  Although a S3 bucket is globally accessible, the underlying resources are still hosted in a specific underlying AWS region.  If you're using the AWS client sdks to access the resources, you need to be connecting to the bucket's regional S3 endpoint.

> Is there any advantage to choose the right location?

Lower latency.  If your services are in `eu-west-1` it makes sense to have your buckets there too.  You also will not pay cross-region data transfer rates, but rather AWS's internal region rate.

> Is there any hidden cost to not match the location?

Yes.  Costs for data egress vary based on region, and you pay more to send data from one region to another than you will to send data between services in the same region.

As to why the boto3 library is not raising an error, it is possibly interrogating the S3 api under the hood to establish where the bucket is located before issuing the `list_objects_v2` call.

Comment: Moreover, authentication can vary according to the region, so without that, it could be impossible to even connect